# Why was this moderator's tag synonym vote not binding?

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, moderators, binding-vote

This is a strange sight to see (click image to enlarge):

[image: screenshot]

Why was this moderator's vote not binding? The tag synonym page shows it as a normal vote:

> [image: screenshot 2]

Is this a bug? It was suggested just now, so it couldn't have been before the user was a mod.

Comment: They suggested it before they were a mod?

Comment: @michaelb958 They suggested it just now.